# Is it possible to use subversion security with file:// repository access method?

Tags: svn

Right now i'm trying to narrow a complex subversion problem and performing lots of small tests with creating and accessing repositories normally via `file://` protocol. I have tried to add some security to such local repository by setting `password-db` and `authz-db` in repository `/conf/svnserve.conf` but seems `svn` client ignores such settings while using `file://` protocol. Is path security possible at all with `file://` protcol or i need to start a svnserve daemon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing a `file://` repository uses the operating system's file functions. You can therefore make use of the filesystem security functionality your OS has: Just configure the permissions to the repository directory via your OS's interface.

For example, to allow only `svnserve` and members of the group `svnusers` access to your repository on a classical UNIX system, execute the following as root:

```
$ chown svnserve:svnusers /my/repository
$ chmod 770 /my/repository
```

Answer (score 0):

With file:// protocol each subversion client is acting as the svn server when accessing the repository. This essentially means that the users are responsible for enforcing their own permissions.

Even if you were able to give users narrow permissions to specific paths within the repository, they would still need read/write OS-level permission to the file:// path which would let them read or even corrupt the whole repository anyway.

If you want real security, you need to host the repository through another service such as svnserve which enforces the user permissions.