# How can I show the authentication dialog in TortoiseSvn using *file* protocol?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a repository created with TortoiseSVN. This repository has configured security as this:

*svnserve.conf*

```
[general]
anon-access = none
auth-access = write
password-db = passwd
authz-db = authz
```

*authz*

```
[/]
admin = rw
editor = rw
reader = r
* =
```

*passwd*

```
[users]
admin = admin$1
editor = editor$1
reader = reader$1
user = user$1
```

How can I show the authentication dialog using *file* protocol?

Comment: You can not do it. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7414126/is-it-possible-to-use-subversion-security-with-file-repository-access-method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can. When you use the `file://` protocol, the client (TortoiseSVN, in your case) accesses the files of the repository directly, so the only permissions/access control mechanisms are the file system ones. And `svnserve.conf` comes into play when working with, well, `svnserve`.

Subversion's user suggests using the `file://` protocol only for single-developer testing or debugging purposes.

If you need access control, try using `svnserve`.

Answer (score 1):

Note the name of the file ***svnserve***.conf.

This file is for configuring access with the built in `svnserve` server process.

You should never use the `file://` protocol except for something that a single developer is working on. For example, your own private stuff. Once you have more than one developer, you should use a protocol built for multiple user access.

The problem with the `file://` protocol is that everyone has complete access to the repository. They can delete it or do a dump, munge the repository history and then reload it.

There is no security in the `file://` protocol at all which would prevent anyone from using your repository since you must make the entire repository directory structure read/writeable to everyone.

Using `svnserve` is very easy and can secure your repository to prevent unauthorized access. All you have to do is make sure that the only user who can read or write to the repository directory structure is the user who is running the `svnserve` process.

Once you do this, the only way another user can touch or even look at the repository is by talking to that server process via a Subversion client.

You've already configured the `svnserve.conf` file, all you need to do is start the `svnserve` process itself (and make sure that only the `svnserve` process can read or write to the repository directory tree.

The main problem is that `svnserve` uses Port 3690 to talk to the clients, and quite a few sites block this port. If this is the case, you need to talk to your IT department about allowing this port to be used. You can run `svnserve` on another port, but that makes things a bit more complex for your clients since they'll have to know the port number as well as the server name.

So, don't use the `file://` protocol. As you found out, there's no security implemented with it. The main use is for learning subversion and for individual projects. However, I have a private Subversion repository on my system, yet I still use `svnserve` and the `svn://` protocol. I find it easy enough to use, and I don't have to keep using the enter repository path every time I need to checkout:

```
$ svn co file:///Users/David/Work/svn_repos/trunk/myfile
```

vs.

```
$ svn co svn://localhost/trunk/myfile
```